# Detect/support both versions v3 and v4 of sqlcipher dbs

Tags: sqlcipher

We are looking to support both versions v3 and v4 of the sqlcipher db in our app. We want to create any new instances of the db in v4, but want to open pre-existing v3 dbs in v3 (ie without any migration). To do this, here is the sequence of steps that we found working, with a relatively recent version of the sqlcipher code:

```
sqlite3 handle;

bool success = false;
for (int versionToTry = 4; versionToTry >= 3; versionToTry--)
{
    sqlite3_open(dbPath, &handle); //error-checking omitted for clarity

    sqlite3_key(handle, key, keyLength); //error-checking omitted for clarity

    if (versionToTry == 3)
        sqlite3_exec(handle, "PRAGMA cipher_compatibility = 3;", NULL, NULL, NULL); //error-checking omitted for clarity

    // check that we can actually operate on the db
    sqlite3_exec(handle, "create table if not exists KeyValTable ...");

    int errCode = sqlite3_errcode(handle);
    if (errCode == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        success = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_close(handle);
        handle = nullptr;
    }
}

// proceed if success is true
```

I see that the step to actually access the db with a non-empty query (eg `"create table..."`) is a necessary step; without this, the version determination will be faulty. E.g., if it’s a v3 db, doing sqlite3_exec with an empty query string will succeed. And doing `sqlite3_exec(handle, "PRAGMA cipher_compatibility = 3")` on a v4 db also will succeed.

A few questions/requests here:

- Is the above sequence the recommended way, or if there a better approach?
- Is it guaranteed that every single db-access on a v3 db will fail if it’s not preceded by the compatibility pragma?

  - If yes, would appreciate any insight on why this is the case.
- In my tests I see sqlcipher returns `SQLITE_NOTADB` (26) error when I attempt to open db with the wrong version. Is this a guaranteed error that sqlcipher returns for version-mismatch, so we can compare against this exact error-code? This would make the logic more precise, so would be preferred.

Another sequence that works ok from experimentation is the sqlcipher_check_connection logic, from [sqlcipher/crypto_impl.c](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/blob/104f2d2fda33f4c179960d628e7446f3869ef4ed/src/crypto_impl.c). But this I don’t think is meant to be used for this purpose. Would you agree?